# How can I rewrite lines in a txt file using grep [sed]?

Tags: files, text, grep

I have a text file where each line has the format like this...

`25126 Akers, David`

And I'm needing to put it in a format like this to insert into a database...

```
25126;Akers, David;
```

Only problem is there might be some with names having spaces like...

```
25257 Ah You, C.J.
```

I was told I should use grep but I'm not sure how to go about doing it.

Comment: Trying to make it clear:
 Does number always follow by space or can there be space in number as well?
 for e.g.
 24 557 name, name
 
 Next does two names (fields) always separated by a comma?

 well if u answer no and yes to above questions then split number on the basis of space and name fields on the basis of comma

Comment: Number is always followed by one space, and the name is always separated by a comma. I'm not familiar enough with grep to know how to do it though. That's why I was hoping someone could help.

Comment: You probably want to use `sed` not `grep`. Also, you might ask in [the unix and linux stackexchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) or even [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) since this is more of a shell question no specific to Ubuntu.

Comment: oh! ok my apologies will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`grep` is not suitable for such a task, because it is a search tool, but if I understand correctly the problem, you can use `sed`, as in the following example:

```
sed 's/^\([0-9]\+\) \(.*\)$/\1;\2;/' input-file >output-file
```

To preventively check that all lines conform to the above pattern, run the following command

```
sed -n '/^\([0-9]\+\) \(.*\)$/!p' input-file
```

that should return nothing.